# Wrong font when displaying superscript numbers

Tags: html, css, font-face

I'm trying to render some superscript numbers like this: ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁰ with a custom font, but only the first 3 numbers display using the current `font-family`. The others display with the default page font.

Here's a working example:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "verveine";
  src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.eot");
  src: url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.woff2")
      format("woff2"),
    url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.woff")
      format("woff"),
    url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.ttf")
      format("truetype"),
    url("//db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/b3fb273a4c9c465126f860b59809fd4a.svg#VerveineW01-Regular")
      format("svg");
}

body {
  font-family: verveine;  
}
```

```html
Test 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0<br/>
Test ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁰
```

But when I go to the [Verveine font page](https://fonts.adobe.com/fonts/verveine) on Adobe's site and enter these superscript numbers, they display correctly:

[image: Superscript numbers displaying correctly on adobe's site]

How can I fix this?

Edit:

For now I'm going with this fairly heavy-handed solution of parsing the text and wrapping each superscript number in a `sup` tag

```
function fixSuperNumbers(input: string): ReactNode[] {
  const supers: Record<string, string> = {
    "¹": "1",
    "²": "2",
    "³": "3",
    "⁴": "4",
    "⁵": "5",
    "⁶": "6",
    "⁷": "7",
    "⁸": "8",
    "⁹": "9",
    "⁰": "0",
  };
  let results: ReactNode[] = [""];

  for (let c of input.split("")) {
    if (supers.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
      results.push(<sup>{supers[c]}</sup>, "");
    } else {
      results[results.length - 1] += c;
    }
  }

  return results.map((result, i) => <Fragment key={i}>{result}</Fragment>);
}
```

Comment: When I try it with `<sup>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</sup>` it [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ot4j8wyq/).

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2URA.png) on Edge 90.0.818.62 (Chrome based)

Comment: @SagarV your screenshot shows the bug. The superscript numbers 4-0 don't match the regular numbers 4-0.

Comment: @j08691 That does work but I'd love to find an answer that doesn't involve transforming the text.

Comment: @SimpleJ Sorry I missed. It's glyph support issue. see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some fonts doesn't support all Unicode characters**. In that case, such characters will use fallback/ system fonts.

When you tested it on **Adobe's site**, you haven't activated the font you mentioned.

[image]

Once you activate the font, you can see that the unicode characters aren't supported by the font.

[image]

The Unicode values of your code are

```
%B9
%B2
%B3
%u2074
%u2075
%u2076
%u2077
%u2078
%u2079
%u2070
```

**1,2 and 3 belongs to `Bx` group and the rest belongs to `207x` group.**

I used [FontDrop](https://fontdrop.info/) to inspect the glyphs and it does support `Bx` group but not `207x` group.

[image]

**That's why you're seeing 1-3 OK and 4-0 Not OK.**

Comment: This makes sense. I'm still confused as to why adobe would show 4-0 correctly in the right font until it's activated. Are they displaying an identical font that has all the unicode superscript numbers?

Comment: Looks like they're using similar alternative font